# Gulp: no such file or directory even though directory exists

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

I have the following folder structure:

```
theme
  assets
    build
      css
        style.css
    src
      theme 
        buttons.scss
      style.scss
  components
    hero
      hero.html
      hero.scss
  index.html
```

I'm trying to get everything to compile into `style.css`. This includes:

- Any changes that occur in any `.scss` file in `src` `theme` folder
- Any changes in `style.scss` should compile the `css` again
- Any changes to a components `scss` file (i.e. `hero.scss`) should compile the `css` again.

To achieve the above, I have the following `gulpfile`:

```
const base          = '/',
      assetsSRC     = 'theme/assets/src/',
      assetsDST     = 'theme/assets/build/',
      components    = 'theme/components/';

const gulp          = require('gulp'),
      sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
      sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
      fs            = require('fs'),
      path          = require('path'),
      merge         = require('merge-stream'),
      postcss       = require('gulp-postcss'),
      autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      plumber       = require('gulp-plumber'),
      concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
      strip         = require('gulp-strip-comments'),
      fileinclude   = require('gulp-file-include');

const componentCSS    = components + '**/component.scss',
      componentJS     = components + '**/component.js',
      globalCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/style.scss';
      configCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/config/**.scss';
      themeCSS        = assetsSRC + 'scss/theme/**.scss';
      globalJS        = assetsSRC + 'js/*.js';
      libJS           = assetsSRC + 'js/lib/*.js';



gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
};

function getFolders(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}


function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(components, folder);
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '/**/src/component.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(rename(function(file) {
        file.dirname = path.dirname(file.dirname);
        file.basename = file.basename;
        return file;
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(src));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}


function mainCSS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
  return gulp.src(globalCSS, { allowEmpty: true })
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function javascript() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(components, folder);
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '/**/src/component.js'))
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      file.dirname = path.dirname(file.dirname);
      file.basename = file.basename;
      return file;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(src));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}


function mainJS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'js/dist');
  return gulp.src([
    globalJS
  ])
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(concat('scripts-min.js'))
  .pipe(strip())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function libraryJS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'JS/lib');
  return gulp.src(libJS).pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function watch() {
  gulp.watch([globalCSS,configCSS,themeCSS],mainCSS);
  gulp.watch([globalJS],mainJS);
  gulp.watch([componentCSS], css);
  gulp.watch([componentJS], javascript);
}


exports.mainCSS = mainCSS;
exports.mainJS = mainJS;
exports.libraryJS = libraryJS;
exports.css = css;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.watch = watch;

const build = gulp.series(watch);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

However, when I run `gulp css`, I get the error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/components/'`

I have tried running `npm rebuild node-sass`, but no luck.

#### Edit

I have made some progress. However, with my below `gulp` setup, multiple `css` files are created in my `css` folder. For example:

```
build
  css
    style.css
    hero.css
```

Whereas I need everything to compile into `style.css`.

```js
const assetsSRC     = 'assets/src/',
      assetsDST     = 'assets/build/',
      components    = 'components/';

const gulp          = require('gulp'),
      sass          = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
      sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
      fs            = require('fs'),
      path          = require('path'),
      merge         = require('merge-stream'),
      postcss       = require('gulp-postcss'),
      autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      plumber       = require('gulp-plumber'),
      concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
      strip         = require('gulp-strip-comments');

const componentCSS    = components + '**/*.scss',
      componentJS     = components + '**/*.js',
      globalCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/style.scss';
      configCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/config/**.scss';
      themeCSS        = assetsSRC + 'scss/theme/**.scss';
      globalJS        = assetsSRC + 'js/*.js';
      libJS           = assetsSRC + 'js/lib/*.js';

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
};

function getFolders(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}


function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css');
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '/**/*.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}


function mainCSS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
  return gulp.src(globalCSS, { allowEmpty: true })
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function libraryJS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'JS/lib');
  return gulp.src(libJS).pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function watch() {
  gulp.watch([globalCSS,configCSS,themeCSS, componentCSS],mainCSS);
}


exports.mainCSS = mainCSS;
exports.mainJS = mainJS;
exports.libraryJS = libraryJS;
exports.css = css;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.watch = watch;

const build = gulp.series(watch);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

#### Edit 2

With my below code, everything that is named `component.scss` under the `components` folder merges into `component.css`.

Seems like I’m at the last hurdle, where instead of a new file called `component.css` being created when I run `gulp css`, I need everything to merge and append to `style.css` instead.

```js
function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '**/component.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(rename(function(file) {
        file.dirname = path.dirname(file.dirname);
        file.basename = file.basename;
        return file;
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}
```

#### Edit 3

Looking into it deeper, not all `component.scss` files are merged into `component.css` (for example, if there are 3 `component.scss` files, `component.css` only has the styles for one of them).

Comment: please check the answer and let me know if i miss something.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [`concat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) in gulp pipeline.

```
function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '**/component.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(rename(function(file) {
        file.dirname = path.dirname(file.dirname);
        file.basename = file.basename;
        return file;
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}
```